# Convert formatted cstring number to long

Tags: c++, format, int, cstring

I need your help 
Just want to convert a cstring like this one 128,140

to int number 128140

I use this function but it fills number with  128  only.

```
 _stscanf(text, _T("%d"), &number);
```

any ideas ??
Thank you :)

Comment: Has the string a fixed format? Like: "ccc,ccc" or is it variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I designed for you this simple function. You can use it as reference code for more complex issue. Following a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

long StingToNumber(string AString)
{
    string LStrNum;
    for(int i=0; i < AString.size(); ++i)
        if( isdigit(AString[i]) )
          LStrNum += AString[i];
    return atoi(LStrNum.c_str());
}

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string LString = "128,140";

    long LNum = StingToNumber("128,140");

    printf("String %s to number %d", LString.c_str(), LNum);

    return 0;
}
```

If my solution help you, please remember to check it as answered.

Ciao (from Italy)
Angelo